# Hibernate not auto generating tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

AYY

I am making a simple Spring MVC web application. I can run the app just fine but if I try to login, I get the following (I trimmed all messages I thought were not relevant):

```
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.6.Final}
org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations{5.0.1.Final}
org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT username, password, enabled FROM Users WHERE username=?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'ElsLoggerSchema.Users' doesn't exist
```

I use spring security to authenticate users. I expect Hibernate to automatically generate the tables, my schema exists but it has no tables. Here's the configuration for spring security:

```
  @Configuration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Import({SpringConfiguration.class})
    public class SecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;  

        // authorizeRequests() -> use-expresions = "true"
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/createaccount","/error", "/register", "/login", "/newaccount", "/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**", "/*", "/").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard").loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                    .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login").invalidateHttpSession(true);
        }


        // Equivalent of jdbc-user-service in XML
        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{

            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, enabled FROM Users WHERE username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, authority FROM authorities where username=?");
        }

    }
```

My persistence configuration for hibnerate is right here, it includes setting Hibernate properties:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @PropertySource({ "/WEB-INF/persistence-mysql.properties" })
    @ComponentScan({ "com.LearnersLogger" })
    @Import({SpringConfiguration.class})
    public class PersistenceConfig {

        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Bean(name="sessionFactory")
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
            sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.LearnersLogger");
            try {
                sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error with instantiating session factory");
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            return sessionFactory;
        }


        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){

            HibernateTransactionManager htm = new HibernateTransactionManager();
            htm.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

            return htm;
        }

        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
            HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
            return hibernateTemplate;
        }

        public Properties hibernateProperties() {

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("hibernate.hbm2dll.auto", this.env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", this.env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            properties.put("hibernate.show", this.env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));

            return properties;
        }

        @Bean
        public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
            return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
        }

    }
```

And my user model looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5729727545813781294L;

    public User(){

    }

    // various attributes typical to a User object model
}
```

I have tried change hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to update, create and create-drop but it had no effect. 
My question is, what am I missing or what might be causing the issue where my application isn't automatically generating the tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo here, prop name should be hibernate.hbm2d**d**l.auto:

```
properties.put("hibernate.hbm2dll.auto", this.env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
```

Comment: Well. Damn. That fixed it. You know what's funny? I remember encountering a thread right here on StackOverflow where the OP made the same mistake and the solution was exactly this typo. I scoffed at it, dismissing any chance I would've made the same mistake and moved on to the next thread. Thanks a lot for spotting it for me xD

Comment: You are welcome. :) The JPA version of the property is longer but probably harder to mistype: `jpaProperties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action", "create");`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this statement: `properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");` for solving your problem